# Is there any way to improve -subimage-search performance

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-recognition

I have a big image of 1600x1600px and a small image of 50x50px. It takes around 3mins 20 sec to run the test. The small image is expected to appear inside big image only within an area of 50 x 500px.

I tried this but it doesn't work:
`compare -metric mse -subimage-search "big.png[50x500+0+118]" "small.png" null:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make `big.gif`:

```
convert -size 1600x1600 xc:yellow -fill black -draw "rectangle 5,130 14,139" big.gif
```

[image]
and `small.gif`

```
convert -size 10x10 xc:black small.gif
```

[image]

Now let's look at the cropped search area:

```
convert big.gif -crop 50x500+0+118 x.gif
```

[image]

So, the command you need would be:

```
convert big.gif -crop 50x500+0+118 +repage miff:- | compare -metric mse -subimage-search miff:- small.gif null:
0 (0) @ 5,12
```

That brings the search time down from 91 seconds to 0.7 seconds.

If your real problem is harder, or bigger, or more pressing, you can split the image into two and do the two halves in parallel - remember to overlap the halves by the size of your sought sub-image:

```
convert big.gif -crop 50x260+0+118 +repage miff:- | compare -metric mse -subimage-search miff:- small.gif null: &
convert big.gif -crop 50x260+0+368 +repage miff:- | compare -metric mse -subimage-search miff:- small.gif null: &
wait
```

Now it takes 0.4 seconds :-)